# How can I use a library on Visual Studio?

Tags: c++

I am trying to use cpr library but I cannot use it properly probably because I can't include the library properly. I tried other libraries like curlpp or plain curl, but every time I tried, I got errors like this:

> cpr::Session::Session(void)" (??0Session@cpr@@QAE@XZ), "class cpr::Response __cdecl cpr::Get,class std::allocator >,class cpr::Authentication,class cpr::Parameters>(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > &&,class cpr::Authentication &&,class cpr::Parameters &&)" (??$Get@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@VAuthentication@cpr@@VParameters@4@@cpr@@YA?AVResponse@0@$$QAV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@$$QAVAuthentication@0@$$QAVParameters@0@@Z)

I think I got this error because of my method of including classes. I need to know how to use these classes with Visual Studio 2017.
I searched everywhere but probably because I don't know what exactly I need to look, I couldn't find anything. 
Here is the library I want to use: https://whoshuu.github.io/cpr/

The solution is learning how to use this kind of libraries with Visual Studio. This is where I need help.

Comment: Too little information to be able to help you, I'm afraid. Are you building these other libraries? Are you [adding the built libraries or a downloaded pre-built library to your project's dependencies?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba1z7822.aspx). Are pre-built libraries compatible with your version of Visual Studio?

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you for response! Well, the problem is I don't really know anything. What I did is installing Visual Studio 2017 and then trying to use c++ libraries by copying directly "main" source code files (Files that are in "includes" directory of CPR") into the main folder of my project. 

So best answer would be answer of what to do after these steps:
1- Download .zip source files: https://github.com/whoshuu/cpr
2- ??
3- Use it.

Comment: If I can't find out how to do it, I think I will have to learn Java instead of C++

Comment: Follow whatever building instructions the library provides or go hunting for libraries prebuilt for MSVS2017. Once you have the libraries built (or downloaded) add them as descrived here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba1z7822.aspx . Or learn Java. It is generally a much more forgiving language, but it has it's own sticky spots.

Comment: Google "visual c++ how to use a library".  Everything on the first page of hits tells you what to do and is worth reading to learn more.

Comment: @HansPassant of course I did it. I wouldn't write here if I hadn't done it before. Anyways, I moved to Java.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you with VS 2017

```
#pragma comment(lib, "Your library name here")
```

Add it to your source.

Comment: Only useful if the asker has a library compiled for VS2017. I do not believe this to be the case.